# javascript alert box not working in FireFox4

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer-8

The JavaScript `alert` box is appearing without close mark on top right side nor its showing any alert symbol as shown below.

[image]

The same in IE8 works fine

[image]

Both are running on Windows 7 platform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is how Firefox 4 renders an alert box. They've gone for a minimalist look.

There's nothing you can do about it -- how the `alert()` function renders its popup is entirely at the discression of the browser, and they all do it slightly differently.

If you want control over how the box looks, you will need to write your own in Javascript, or use one of the hundreds of Javascript and JQuery examples written by other people who have already found they need more flexibility than the standard alert box can give them.

[EDIT]

Here's a blog post where the change to how the alert box works is discussed: http://www.derekallard.com/blog/post/firefox-4-alert-boxes/

There's actually a lot more that's changed than just how it looks; it actually works quite differently too in FF4.